# Using a FloatingActionButton on different pages if using a Backdrop?

Tags: flutter

I'm learning Flutter and using the Shrine demo app ( https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-101-flutter/ ) they provide as a base for trying out other widgets.
I'm using the Shrine menu for navigation as an alternative to a Drawer.

I've got a few different routes/pages, and I want each to have their own FloatingActionButton that performs different functions on each of them, with no button on some of them, and maybe a BottomAppBar on some others.

In order to use a FloatingActionButton it needs to be passed as an argument to a Scaffold, but the Shrine Backdrop only has one Scaffold, which also holds the state for which menu option is selected.

If each page had its own Scaffold then this would be easy, but then I'd lose the cool menu that the Shrine app has.

How could I use the Shrine style menu with multiple different pages, each with their own unique FloatingActionButton or BottomAppBar?

Should I be moving menu state elsewhere? Should I somehow pass a button action from the child widget back up to the Backdrop's Scaffold (if so, how)? Should I give up and use a Drawer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the FloactingActionButton property in a Scaffold, you can position the button at the bottom right of your pages with the 'Positioned' widget in individual pages.

For example:

```
         body: Stack( // must add Stack widget
               chidren: <Widget> [
               .
               .
               . // your other widgets on this page
               .
                Positioned(
                          right: 10,
                          bottom: 10,
                          child: FloatingActionButton(
                            onPressed: () => yourFunction,
                            ),
                            child: Icon(Icons.add),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          ),
                        ),
            ],
        );
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Neat, I didn't know you could combine Positioned and Stack like that. Which part of the Flutter docs should I read to get better at this? If I was wanting to add a BottomAppBar for another one of the views, how would I best do that? Do I need to refactor or is it best to only use BottomAppBar's inside Scaffolds?

Comment: Looks like it's possible to also use BottomAppBar inside a Positioned in a Stack if you set bottom, left, and right to 0. It feels kind of like I'm fighting flutter by doing it this way. Is there a "best practices" way to do this without just switching to a Drawer and having separate Scaffolds on each page?

Comment: I have never used a BottomAppBar before so I can't really comment whether it is a bad coding practice to use it with 'Positioned'. And I didn't read the doc for the solution, just trial and error by combining things together. Just like playing with LEGOs :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll have to figure it out for myself.